# Terraform BigQuery replaces table & deletes the data when schema gets updated

Tags: google-bigquery, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, bigquery-udf

I have somewhat below folder structure:

```
.
├── locals.tf
├── main.tf
├── modules
│   ├── bigquery
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── schema
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   ├── bigquery_tables
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── schema
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   ├── bigquery_views
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── queries
│   │   ├── schema
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   ├── cloud_composer
│   ├── list_projects
├── providers.tf
├── storage.tf
├── variables.tf
└── versions.tf
```

& my main.tf in bigquery_tables is:

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "bq_tables" {
  for_each            = { for table in var.bigquery_dataset_tables : table.table_id => table }
  project             = var.project_id
  dataset_id          = each.value.dataset_id
  table_id            = each.value.table_id
  schema              = file(format("${path.module}/schema/%v.json", each.value.file_name))
  deletion_protection = false
  dynamic "time_partitioning" {
    for_each = try(each.value.time_partition, false) == false ? [] : [each.value.time_partition]
    content {
      type  = each.value.partitioning_type
      field = each.value.partitioning_field
    }
  }
}
```

The issue I am facing is since things are in development stage we have frequent update in schema.
Thus this change in schema is causing the BigQuery table to be replaced by terraform & also leading to data loss in BigQuery.

**Can some one suggest a solution like what I should add in by resource block to avoid replacing the table & data loss?**

I am unsure how can I add "external_data_configuration" in my current block as per https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/10919.

Comment: Your updates correspond to adding new columns or you also remove or rename columns ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun, We are usually changing the Type & Mode in the schema.

Comment: @MazlumTosun, setting deletion_protection=true will not update the schema as it needs to be destroyed per the behaviour I am facing here.

Also I am using folder structure having modules & not workspace. (updated in question)

I see the below answer. I am not pretty sure that this avoids Data loss from table & also if the schema change will only update the terraform in-place?

Comment: Temporary if each execution and Terraform apply in done in a different workspace, It will always create a new table in a different dataset, in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if you change the schema structure of the `BigQuery` table, you will have this behaviour.

For the `deletion_protection` param, I think it's better to set it to true to prevent data loss or not set it (it' true by default).

The solution I saw, because you are in dev mode, it's using the `Terraform` [workspace](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state/workspaces) and run your schema updates in a separated workspace.

It will create a new dataset or table in each apply, example :

`locals.tf` file :

```
locals {
  workspace = terraform.workspace != "default" ? "${terraform.workspace}_" : ""
}
```

`main.tf` file :

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "bq_tables" {
  for_each            = { for table in var.bigquery_dataset_tables : table.table_id => table }
  project             = var.project_id
  dataset_id          = "${local.workspace}${each.value.dataset_id}"
  table_id            = each.value.table_id
  schema              = file(format("${path.module}/schema/%v.json", each.value.file_name))
  deletion_protection = false
  dynamic "time_partitioning" {
    for_each = try(each.value.time_partition, false) == false ? [] : [each.value.time_partition]
    content {
      type  = each.value.partitioning_type
      field = each.value.partitioning_field
    }
  }
}
```

In this example, I used the workspace as prefix of `dataset ID`, if the default workspace is used, the prefix is empty, otherwise equals to the given workspace :

```
dataset=mydataset

- workspace=default => dataset=mydataset
- workspace=evolfeature1 => dataset=evolfeature1_mydataset
```